# input value of numbers form is always 0 when trying to calculate in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I'm trying to calculate a price based on the number input of user. But when I try to get the value of that input field it always says 0. Can anyone help me?

```js
const calculateCost = () => {
  const $input = document.getElementById('amountOfCards').value;
  const $addbutton = document.getElementById('calculatePrice');
  $addbutton.onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById('order__cost__price').innerHTML = $input * 1.5;
  }
}

calculateCost();
```

```html
<label for="amountOfCards" class="order__amount"> Amount</label>

<input type="number" min="1" max="10000" step="2" value="" id="amountOfCards">

<button type="button" id="calculatePrice">Calculate</button>
<div class="order__cost">
  <p>Total:</p>
  <p id="order__cost__price"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Here is a pen..."* Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), not off-site tools. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
const calculateCost = () => {
    const $addbutton = document.getElementById('calculatePrice');
    $addbutton.onclick = () => {
       const $input = document.getElementById('amountOfCards').value;
        document.getElementById('order__cost__price').innerHTML = $input*1.5;
    }
}
```

You're getting the value before the user click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're getting the value right away, before the user clicks.

Instead, get the value when the user clicks:

```
const calculateCost = () => {
    const $input = document.getElementById('amountOfCards').value;
    document.getElementById('order__cost__price').innerHTML = $input * 1.5;
};
const hookupEvents = () => {
  const $addbutton = document.getElementById('calculatePrice');
  $addbutton.onclick = calculateCost;
};
hookupEvents();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const calculateCost = () => {
  document.getElementById('calculatePrice').onclick = () => {
    const $input = parseInt(document.getElementById('amountOfCards').value);
    document.getElementById('order__cost__price').innerHTML = $input * 1.5;
  }
}

calculateCost();
```

```html
<label for="amountOfCards" class="order__amount"> Amount</label>

<input type="number" min="1" max="10000" step="2" value="" id="amountOfCards">

<button type="button" id="calculatePrice">Calculate</button>
<div class="order__cost">
  <p>Total:</p>
  <p id="order__cost__price"></p>
</div>
```

Your `$input` variable was outside of the scope (it's value was the initial one which is an empty string) and before doing any multiplication, convert user's input to number.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is that you are not Parsing the string, when you get the value of an input with `var value = document.getEelementById("something").value` you get a string of what's inside the Input.

So if the input is a number it will be returned like a string. "3"; "2"... 
Also you are getting the value of the input before the user has clicked in the button:

```
const calculateCost = () => {
  const $addbutton = document.getElementById('calculatePrice');
  $addbutton.onclick = () => {
    const $input = document.getElementById('amountOfCards').value;
    var aux = parseInt($input)
    document.getElementById('order__cost__price').innerHTML = (aux*1.5).toString();
   }
  }
calculateCost()
```

Basically you parseInt() it and then you convert it to string again when putting it in the `<p>` again.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving "0" because you are not calling function "calculateCost()" each time when you click on the button. Right now it is triggered when document loads. I have modified your code as below. I hope this is what you need.

```js
const calculateCost = () => {
        const $input = document.getElementById('amountOfCards').value;
        document.getElementById('order__cost__price').innerHTML = $input * 1.5;
   
}
```

```html
<label for="amountOfCards" class="order__amount"> Amount</label>

<input type="number" min="1" max="10000" step="2" value="" id="amountOfCards">
            
<button type="button" onclick="calculateCost();" id="calculatePrice">Calculate</button>
<div class="order__cost">
<p>Total:</p>
<p id="order__cost__price"></p> </div></body>
```